# java regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression for somethin like

```
s1 = I am at Boston at Dowtown
s2 = I am at Miami
```

I am interested in the words after at eg: Boston, Downtown, Miami

I have not been successful in creating a  regex for that. Somethin like

```
> .*? (at \w+)+.*
```

gives  just Boston in s1 (Downtown is missed). it just matches the first "at" Any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to expect `(at \w+)+` to match both `at Boston` and `at Downtown` in the first string.  That doesn't work because you don't allow for the space before the second `at`.  You would need to change it to `( at \w+)+`--or better, change that to a non-capturing group and use the capturing group for the part that really interests you:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*?(?: at (\\w+))+.*");
String s1 = "I am at Boston at Downtown";
Matcher m = p.matcher(s1);
if (m.matches()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

But now it only prints `Downtown`.  That's because you're trying to use one capturing group to capture two substrings.  The first time `(?: at (\\w+))+` matches, it captures `Boston`; the second time, it discards `Boston` and captures `Downtown` instead.

There are some regex flavors that will let you retrieve intermediate captures (`Boston` in this example), but Java is not one of them.  Your best option is probably to use `find()` instead of `matches()`, as @arclight suggested.  That makes the regex simpler, too:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\bat\\s+(\\w+)");
String s1 = "I am at Boston at Downtown";
Matcher m = p.matcher(s1);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

You don't have to match the space before `at` any more, but you probably want to use the `\b` (word boundary) to avoid partial-word matches (e.g., *My c**at** is at Boston at Downtown*).  And it's usually a good idea to use `\s+` instead of a literal space, in case there are multiple spaces, or the space is really a TAB or something.

Comment: +1; I really wish that Java can do "intermediate captures" (is that what they're called?). I think C# does this. And it can do infinite lookbehind too, which I've figured now how to (ab)use in Java quite reliably.

Comment: also, this can still miss stuff like `"I'm at at Boston"`, but that's probably ok.

Comment: @poly, Good call. But it's easy enough to fix: `"\\bat\\s+((?!at\\b)\\w+)"`. And yes, the .NET regex flavor supports intermediate captures.  The only other flavor I know of that supports them is Perl.

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
 at\s+(\w+)
```

The complete code snippet would be

```
Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile("at\\s+(\\w+)", Pattern.DOTALL, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = myPattern.matcher(yourString);

while(m.find()) {
  String word = m.group(1);
}
```

Comment: This. You're matching the entire of at[whitespace][word], but the word is in (), so you're only returning the word for group. Of course, you're going to have problems if you say "I am at the ball field", because this will match "at the" and return "the".